# Term transformation to "see" some limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It's intuitivle clear that the $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n+47} - \sqrt{n}$$ is 0,
But is there a way to transform the term to make that absolutly clear?

Answer (score 3):

You may write
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n+47} - \sqrt{n}=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(\sqrt{n+47} - \sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+47} + \sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+47}+ \sqrt{n}}=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{47}{\sqrt{n+47}+ \sqrt{n}}$$ Hoping you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n+47}+\sqrt{n}$. Then use
$$
a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for sequences of the form $$a_n=\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n}$$ one can often try the following: $$a_n=\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{(\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n})\cdot (\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your function will equal $\frac{47}{\sqrt{n+47}+\sqrt{n}}$. So $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{47}{\sqrt{n+47}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{47}{\infty}=0$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt{n+47} + \sqrt{n}$ works.

More generically,$\sqrt{n+47} - \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{1+\frac{47}{n}}-1)$
$>= \sqrt{n}(1+\frac{47}{2n}-1)=\frac{47}{2\sqrt{n}}$ (for $n \ge 0$)
So , the limit is indeed 0